# Unwanted mosfet turn on and irregular duty cycle when driving with IR2110 how to fix?

Tags: mosfet, buck, mosfet-driver

I am designing an MPPT charge controller and testing all the different components. At the time of writing I am testing the buck converter.

During testing, I used a 10 ohm load instead of the battery and the following setup

- R7 is a high side shunt resistor (value to be determined)
- C7 and R8 (RC snubber, values to be determined) were not used in my test
- D4 was not used in my test
- D2 is a 1N4007 diode
- C4 and C5 are 50 nF polyester capacitors
- C2 is 100uF electrolitic
- PWM is 50 kHz 0-5V signal
- Atmega328p is driving the gate driver IR2110.
- Buck converter input voltage: 30V

[image]

I tested the circuit with a fixed duty cycle and noticed 2 problems (point 1 and 2) which may be related to the gate driver:

1. The gate pulse to drive the mosfet is not always consistent with the PWM signal from the ATmega (see picture 1, high duty cycle, AC coupling).
2. The mosfet seems to turn on slightly at the wrong time (see picture 2, 10% duty cycle).
3. I will remove the ringing using the RC snubber at a later stage.
4. I think D4 is not needed in this circuit.

Where are these problems (1 and 2) coming from? I thought using a mosfet driver would remove much of the "driving" related problems.
Picture 1
[image: Picture 1]
Picture 2
[image]

Comment: The o-scope pictures are confusing. If you make statements like *The mosfet seems to turn on slightly at the wrong time* then you ought to show both traces. Plus, who knows which picture is which?

Comment: If you see picture 2 you can see that the signal on the output is high for 10% of the time, zero for about 45% and not zero for about 45 %.

Comment: But what are you probing, how are you probing and what else is changing? Maybe show two probings with one being the gate and the other being the source of the MOSFET (positive rail) shown together in the same picture.

Comment: I'm afraid that's all I have right now :) As soon as I will get back at it, I'll try to record better data

Comment: @mickkk Please **update** your question (using the edit link), so people don't need to read all the comments to get a clearer picture (pun intended).